# Parcelable array passed with kotlin is emitting last item

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to pass an array to my activity, but for some odd reason the last item of the array is passed as null

Here's the code

Helper function to create the intent:

```
@JvmStatic
        fun newTutorProfile(context: Context, webinars: List<Webinar>): Intent {
            val tutorActivity = Intent(context, TutorWebinarProfileActivity::class.java)
            tutorActivity.putExtra(WEBINARS_ARG, webinars.toTypedArray()) // Array contains two valid elements
            return tutorActivity
        }
```

Extracting the array from the intent:

```
webinars = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(WEBINARS_ARG).map { it as Webinar } // array contains two elemnts but the second one is now null
```

Comment: where did your `webinars` create at?

Comment: I'm don't think it matters, the list has two elements when bundled to the intent